# Mechanism of Possible Acid Catalysed Ring Opening

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

Here's a problem I'm stuck with -

[image]
The first step looks like the usual addition of hydroxylamine to the ketone, resulting in two diastereomeric oximes (*this is probably what (A) is*). Further, in the second step, the acid can protonate the hydroxyl group of the oxime, or catalyse ring opening.  I don't see how to decide which one occurs.

Moreover, the final product **doesn't contain three and four membered rings at all - and has a cyanide group!** *I wonder how that happened*. Please help me figure out the mechanism for the conversion, thank you!

Comment: This looks like a variatiant of the Beckmann fragmentation

Comment: The first problem is that the reactant has eleven carbons and the product ten. A search of Chem. Absts. does not locate the reactant. The product is formed by acid-catalyzed fragmentation of the oxime of camphor via a second order Beckmann reaction. https://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/ja01320a046 @Waylander